# Sketchup ruby definitionlist load method error: Invalid component file

Tags: ruby, sketchup

When I create a script file and load it from the console with:

```
load '//192.168.0.0/Mağaza/script.rb'
```

I get 'Invalid component file' error for:

```
someModel = Sketchup.active_model.definitions.load '//192.168.0.0/Mağaza/Definitions/model.skp'
```

But when running the code directly in console, it works.

Any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

`DefinitionList.load` is a completely different method from Ruby's `load`.

To load a component from a URL you need to use `model.definitions.load_from_url`:
http://www.sketchup.com/intl/en/developer/docs/ourdoc/definitionlist#load_from_url

Comment: I'm tring to add definitions to definition list with DefinitionList.load. When I try to run DefinitionList.load method directly from console I get no error. To add multiple definitions I'm using a script and use Ruby's load method to load the script. But I get 'invalid component file' file error when I use the script. Also tried 'load_from_url' method and got 'Invalid component URL' error.

Comment: Are you actually loading files from your local machine?

Comment: Does it fail for all files, or is it just one of the files on your list?

Comment: It fails for all files. The files are in our file server.

Comment: `load_from_url` - you need to provide an http path to use that.
But looking at the source for both of these methods I find notes that download might fail if a transaction is open. Perhaps the batch script fails because multiple transactions are open while it tries to load the components. Hard to debug right now as I don't have a local file server to test with. I need to chat with my colleagues. However, I was able to download from my private web server using `load_from_url`.

Comment: The problem is the character ğ in my folder name. I did't use the folder name in my original post since it was not an English word but the origin of the error was the name.

Comment: Are you using SU2014 - or older versions? Prior to SU2014 SketchUp used Ruby 1.8.

Comment: Older. SU2013. That explains character problem.

Answer (score 0):

After two days, I figured out that the problem was the encoding of 'ğ' in the folder name (mağaza). I tried ANSI and UTF-8 encoding in my script file but nothing changed. But when print the path name in the console, it turned out that the character was not encoding properly.